# PHP form function is working but returns blank page

Tags: php, html

I'm working on a function to upload images to my website fileserver and at the same time would create a thumb preview and create an entry to my mysql database. So long the function to upload_image() is working, it uploads the image and creates a thumb perfectly.

The issue is, that when I click the submit button to upload the image selected, the PHP function do its job but will return a BLANK PAGE. Yes, I know, "another blank page of death question, go find all the other 53 posts related to this question and find a solution" right? Well, it's not that simple.

I have tried every single method in those questions and another bunch that I've found over this forsaken place called internet and nothing works for me, I always get the same Blank Page of death with no warning or error.

What have I tried would you ask? The following would just represent a relevant set of solutions that I recall:

1. Configuring PHP.INI's options for error: DONE. Even creating the log file for every single detailed error.
2. Overriding PHP.INI's options from the php file function with the settings: DONE. Also I have used a script from some answers that override error log protocol.
3. Place an exit('wtf') function from start to bottom to see if its an Syntax error or an error on a certain line: DONE. Every single line will print WTF on the god forsaken Blank Page.

Well, there are other solutions I have tried, be my guest and offer some answers and I would tell you if I have already tried it.

Lets get to it then. My HTML code that calls the php file is:

```
<form action="assets/php/image_uploader.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">                        
    <input type="file" name="myfile" id="fileToUpload">
    </br>
    </br>
    <input type="text" name="title" value="Titulo" size="64">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

And my image_uploader.php code is:

```
<?php
function upload_image()
{
$root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);

$name =  "image_" . date('Y-m-d-H-i-s') . "_" . uniqid() . ".jpg";
$type= $_FILES["myfile"]["type"];
$size= $_FILES["myfile"]["size"];
$temp= $_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"];
$error= $_FILES["myfile"]["error"];

if ($error > 0)
{
    die("Error uploading file! code $error.");
}
else
{
    if($type=="image/png" || $size > 2000000)//condition for the file
    {
        die("Format  not allowed or file size too big!");
    }   
    else
    {
        if(move_uploaded_file($temp, $root . "/images/fulls/" . $name))
        {
            list($ancho, $alto) = getimagesize($root . "/images/fulls/" .$name);
            $nuevo_alto = 212;
            $nuevo_ancho = 212;
            $dx = 0;
            $dy = 0;
            $sx = 0;
            $sy = 0;
            if($ancho == $alto)
            {           
            }
            else
            {
                if($ancho > $alto)
                {
                    $nuevo_ancho = $ancho * (212/$alto);
                }
                else
                {
                    $sy = $alto/2 - $nuevo_alto/2;
                    $alto = $ancho;
                }
            }
            $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($nuevo_ancho, $nuevo_alto);
            $origen = imagecreatefromjpeg($root . "/images/fulls/" .$name);
            imagecopyresampled($thumb, $origen, $dx, $dy, $sx, $sy, $nuevo_ancho, $nuevo_alto, $ancho, $alto);
            imagejpeg($thumb, $root . "/images/thumbs/" .$name);
            imagedestroy($thumb);
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["myfile"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        }
    }
}
}
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   upload_image();
} 
?>
```

Comment: Please bare in mind this is Joomla and form actions are not the same. You can just link to a PHP file like that. I won't say read through loads of questions as I know development for Joomla can be hard at first as we've all been there, but to see how a simple form works, maybe look at the Login module ;) Reading through the documentation will also show you how to use Joomla coding standards, for example, not using `$_POST`, `$_FILES` or `date()`. Joomla has it's own API so for security, validation and simply better code, I'd suggest using it

Comment: @Lodder excuse my ignorance but; Why are you mentioning Joomla?

Comment: Oh crap. Sorry posted this on the wrong tab. **goes to bed**

Comment: Hehehe, Ok @Lodder buddy, take a napper ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placed the code into the HTML file which was renamed later to have the extension .php and called the function in the form section as:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="myfile" id="fileToUpload">
</br>
</br>
<input type="text" name="title" value="Titulo" size="64">
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

And now it works as if it was magic, I do not know if htmlspecialchar() function has anything to do with it, but now the code works with no errors. Therefore I would post this as an answer but reminding you to not consider this as a solution to the BLANK PAGE death screen.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$new_file = $root . "/images/fulls/" . $name;
copy($temp, $new_file);
if(!is_file($new_file)) {
    die('cannot copy file');
}
```

also wrap main part with:

```
try{

}
catch(Exception $ex) {die('['.$ex->getLine().'] '.$ex->getMessage());}
```

Comment: Thanks for that swift answer, but this wont display any errors on the Blank Page of Death and its still Blank.

Comment: maybe try to debug script by adding die("breakpoint"); to catch the line where it breaks, your file is not so big.

Comment: I think it's memory limit issue, when You're creating image, try to increase memory limit for this operation: ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');

Comment: actually, That was the "exit('wtf`')" solution I was talking about, acording to that test, all the code runs, all. Thats the ECHO at the end, it always shows up.

Comment: Nothing, same results. Already tried that before but I didn't mentioned it because is an jpg medium file, doesn't use too much memory.

Comment: Wrapped the code in the TRY{}CATCH( ) but no message from it and the file still uploads and the thumb stills is created.
EDIT:
Regarding the new code, well I used $tmp instead of $temp since I already used it for the upload file reference, but it doesnt show any error message with $tmp and with $temp says it cant copy it since the file was already uploaded.

Comment: I've copied Your code and run it on my local pc - it works fine. it looks like problem with server configuration, or memory allocation, something else.
screenshot: http://joxi.ru/Ra2X77bSOb4jmg